# Django - Read and write from a plain text

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to read and then write from a plain text in Django.

Basically I want to open a file, get an specific word and then change it for whatever else.

Here's what I have:

```
def address_L1():
    file = open("interfaces.txt","r")
    content = file.read()
    file.close()
    address = re.findall('address\s(.*?)\s',open('interfaces.txt','r').read())
    if address:
        print address[0]
    else:
        print 'no Address found!'
    return address[0]
```

Here I'm opening a file and search for the word next to `address`, which is `192.168.5.5` and works perfect.

```
def get_interfaces(request):
    address = str(address_L1())
    if 'address' in request.POST:
        write_template(request)#This is for my writing function
    return render(request, 'interfaces.html', {'address':address})
```

Here I'm passing to template what's in `address` I mean, `192.168.5.5` will be shown in template.

```
<form method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}
    <label for="your_name">Address: </label>
    <input id="your_name" type="text" name="address" value="{{ address }}">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" class="btn  btn-success btn-xs" value="Guardar Cambios">
</form>
```

Here is my html were I'm displaying my variable, There's an input `Address` that will show my `192.168.5.5` or whatever is in `address` variable.

Everything works ok until now.

Now I'm trying to write to my plain text.

```
def write_template(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        get_address = address_L1()
        change_address_L1 = request.GET.get("address", None)#Doing something with my input field in template
        filedata= None
        with open('interfaces.txt', 'r') as f:
            filedata = f.readlines()
            filedata=filedata.replace(get_address , change_address_L1)
            with open('interfaces.txt', 'wb') as f:
                f.writelines(filedata)
    return render(request, 'interfaces.html')
```

Here basically what I want to do is get what's in my `input address` and replace for whatever I enter, I mean when I run my code I ll see my input with `192.168.5.5` I want to delete that value and enter `192.168.0.0` and change my value. When I try so I get this error:

> 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

How can I solve this? how can I successful write in my plain text properly?
What am I doing wrong? **thanks in advance!!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, `filedata` is a list. That's because `f.readlines()` gives you a list, where each element is a line in the file.

If you want the whole thing as a single string, do `f.read()` instead.

Comment: Thank you, now I'm getting the following error `expected a string or other character buffer object` due to `change_address_L1 = request.GET.get("address", None)`  if I try `filedata=filedata.replace(get_address , '0.0.0.0')` works as expected but I want to replace `get_address` for `change_address_L1` . How can I solve this?

Comment: Since the form's action is "post", the value will be in `request.POST` not `request.GET`.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, changed my item but after that got this `list index out of range`